# Javascript sort array of objects by user supplied value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

This is not a duplicate because I want to select the order based on the chosen category by the user.

Trying to sort an array of objects by category array field i.e sort by user selected category from maybe a selected list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barne1y', 'age': 34, 'category':['a','b','c','d','e']},
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'category':['a','b','c','d']},
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48, 'category':['a','b'] },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'category':['a','b','c']}
];
```

example:
 I have a list of users that can be appear in multiple categories as shown in the json data above then in the UI I have a selected list with all the possible categories e.g.

```html
<select><option>a</option><option>b</option><option>c</option><option>d</option></select>
```

When an option e.g a is selected the data is then sorted using that value found in the category.

Comment: plenty of typos in your example

Comment: Post an example of the expected result!

Comment: where is grade property?

Comment: Are you sure you want the value of `category` to be an array whose single value is a comma-delimited string? In other words, do you not mean `['a', 'b']`? Are these values to be involved in the sort?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort this collection by using `Array.prototype.sort()` and passing in a compare function:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barne1y', 'age': 34, 'category':['a,b,c,d,e']},
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'category':['a,b,c,d']},
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48, 'category':['a,b'] },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'category':['a,b,c']}
]; 

var sortedUsers = users.sort(sortByAge);

function sortByAge(a, b) {
  return a.age - b.age;
}
```

Comment: that was a typo @hackerrdave I have since corrected it.

Comment: if it was sort by age it would be a duplicate but i wanted to sort by category value coming from the user

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barne1y', 'age': 34, 'category':['a','b','c','d','e']},
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'category':['a','b','c','d']},
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48, 'category':['a','b'] },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'category':['a','b','c']}
];

users.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.category.length - b.category.length; // reverse the order if you want descending sort
});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: thanks @ibrahim mahrir for your solution but the problem I had was that I wanted to want to sort via a value selected from a dropdown list.

Comment: @kdev check the link for the duplicate. It has what you need!

Comment: its not a duplicate since want to sort by category value coming from the user

Comment: @kdev Post some example. The question still a little bit foggy!

Comment: @kdev do you mean `filter`? (**i.e** show only the users that have that category)?

Comment: nope, imagine a list of posts, some belong to multiple categories but you now need to order them by a category called 'books'...
 some posts may belong to 'books' only and some belong to both magazines and books. How would you go about ordering them?